# Verify input origin of a sObject field

Tags: validation-rule

I have a field that is filled by file import, so I need to check if this field was fill by hand or imported.
Is there any way to implement a validation rule with a condition that verifies whether or not the input of a sObject field was given by the keyboard?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  If you looked at who was responsible for the imports (CreatedById) you could somehow filter by that.  Visualforce & Lighting support onKeyUp & onKeyDown but I don't think that the standard platform functionality allows you to see whether the text entry is by keyboard or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a validation rule cannot determine if the source of a DML operation was from the UI or API. It is theoretically possible to [determine some contexts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/131140), but you would need to write a trigger to get that level of detail.